# Shifting positional arguments after call to getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

Getopts uses OPTIND to store the positional argument number.  It is then a practice to shift the positional arguments in the following way.

```
  shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"
```

For what purpose does one do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of shifting the positional arguments using `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"` after using getopts is to remove all the options and their corresponding arguments that have already been processed by getopts. This ensures that the remaining arguments are the non-option arguments that can be processed separately. `OPTIND` contains the index of the next argument to be processed by getopts, so subtracting 1 from it gives the number of options processed, which is the number of arguments to shift.

Comment: Meaning that one should pass only the options defined in the `optstring` before passing anything else, am I correct?

Comment: @Bennings, yes, in the sense that `getopts` will stop processing options at the first non-option argument it encounters, consistent with conventional POSIX argument-interpretation behavior.

Comment: @Bennings "Traditional" unix convention requires that all options come before any of the positional (non-option) parameters, and that's all that `getopts` supports.